# How can I open the file with the most matches for a given regex?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, grep, pipe

Let's say I have a directory `~/mydir` that has a whole bunch of text files in it.  I want to search for `searchterm` in this directory and then view the file that has the most matches.  How can I do this using only one command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the following line in a script will do it:

```
grep -c "$1" ~/mydir/* | grep -v ':0' | sort -t: -k2 -r -n | head -1 | sed 's/:.*//' | xargs less
```

Then just call `./myscript searchterm`

If you want to search recursively, change `-c` to `-cr` in the first `grep` command.

The parts of this pipeline, in order:

```
grep -c "$1" ~/mydir/*    # Outputs a list of the files in ~/mydir/ with :<count>
                          # appended to each, where <count> is the number of
                          # matches of the $1 pattern in the file.

grep -v ':0'              # Removes the files that have 0 results from
                          # the list.

sort -t: -k2 -r -n        # Sorts the list in reverse numerical order
                          # (highest numbers first) based on the
                          # second ':'-delimited field

head -1                   # Extracts only the first result
                          # (the most matches)

sed 's/:.*//'             # Removes the trailing ':<count>' as we're
                          # done with it

xargs less                # Passes the resulting filename as
                          # an argument to less
```

If there is no match at all, less will open empty.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough

```
grep -c 'pattern' ~/mydir/* 2>/dev/null| sort -rk2n -t:| sed 's/:.*//;q'
```

Comment: Except it returns an arbitrary file if there are no results at all.  But good to know!  With that I can take out the `head` call in my command.